# How can I use Kinect for voice chat during gaming?

Tags: kinect, voice-chat, xbox-one

How do we use the Kinect to chat instead of a headset for game chat?

For example, using Kinect for chat while playing Call of Duty: Ghosts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the Kinect microphone to chat while playing games, press the Xbox button and choose "Settings" followed by "Kinect".

Ensure that the Kinect sensor is enabled and that it can hear you (if your Kinect can't hear you, select "Kinect doesn't hear me" and go through the audio calibration process).

Select "Chat Microphone" and turn this to "on". This will default to using the Kinect microphone in game.

If you need to mute the Kinect microphone to send a voice command to your Xbox, you can do so by hovering your hand over the speech icon in the lower right corner of the screen.