# How do I use a Kinect as a mic while using headphones?

Tags: xbox-one, kinect

I recently moved my Xbox One to my computer monitor instead of my TV. I want to use a headset, so I plugged it into the jack on my controller. The problem is my headphones don't have a mic, but the Xbox thinks it does. Is there a way to only use my Kinect for my mic?

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/143255/163757) since you are trying to use the kinect in conjunction with a headset, but try the answer to that question and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only if you have:

- An external pair of speakers with RCA jacks on the back

  ----------------or-----------------
- An optical input and a 3.5 mm jack for headphones.

---

You would need to then buy:

- An optical converter (if you don't have that optical input on the external speakers)
- An optical cable from a place like radio shack and plug the red and white cables into the converter from the external speakers.

Finally, plug the Optical cable into the converter and run that to the optical jack on the back of the Xbox. Go to settings and change your audio settings to use the current setup.

Comment: In the part "and a cable from a place like radio shack", you need to specify what cable - I guessed it was a optical cable

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using two profiles. You assign the Kinect to one profile and start the party on said profile. Then you can use your primary gaming profile with the headset assigned to that one. You should be able to now use both.